# Invalid phone number format on Cognito signup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Im tryng to create a new user on my cognito user pool via nodeJS but i keep getting wrong phone number error...but i use the same format of number to send SMS via SNS services, i dont understand why this is happening

signup method:

```
module.exports.post = async (username,password,email,phoneNumber) => {
    const environment = {
        UserPoolId: xxxxxxx,
        ClientId: xxxxxx,
    }
    return new Promise((reject,resolve) => {
        const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(environment);
        const emailData = {
            Name: 'Email',
            Value: email
        };
        const userData = {
            Name: 'Usuário',
            Value: username
        };
        const phoneData = {
            Name: 'Telefone',
            Value: phoneNumber
        };
        const emailAttribute = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(emailData);
        const userAttribute = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(userData);
        const phoneAttribute = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(phoneData);

        userPool.signUp(username,password,[emailAttribute,userAttribute, phoneAttribute], null, (err,data) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

the number format im passing:

```
+5521979724910
```

the error :

```
{ code: 'InvalidParameterException',
  name: 'InvalidParameterException',
  message: '1 validation error detected: Value \'phone number\' at \'userAttributes.2.member.name\' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}]+' }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Name` attribute value should be `phone_number` instead of `Telefone`

```
const phoneData = {
        Name : 'phone_number',
        Value : '+15555555555'
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

use attribute name as 'phone_number'

**Note:**  add the country code along with the phone number value. Otherwise it will throw another error